# How do I locate and move image files by parameters/characteristics in an automated manner?

Tags: windows, images, search

I have received a large set of images. Some in greyscale, others in color. They are all in a mix of tiff, png, jpeg, etc... They are all in my local drive.

My objective is to separate those images by the color palette (just by greyscale or fully colored), by image size (width and height), by file size, etc... into different directories.

There's no requirement on the processing order as what I require filtering is by applying `and` to all rules I want. I.e. Only images that match all criteria.

How do I automate this?

Comment: I've removed the software rec portion of your question because it's off-topic here. If you must ask for a program, you can delete this and re-post over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: So what exactly do you want to categorise based on? First by number of colours, then by resolution... or what?

Comment: @karan There's no order list. It is an `and` applied to all of them. If the image matches it, it is moved to the destination directory

Comment: Ok, multiple criteria but there has to be some order, right? Or you want only images that match all specified criteria to be moved and the rest left alone?

Comment: @karan. The latter, yes. Only do something if it matches all criteria.

Comment: I'll test some things and get back to you, but not right away. Meanwhile hopefully someone else will post a good answer. Wonder why the downvote though? I edited the question to be on-topic.

Comment: @karan Thank you. I'm not in a hurry but I really wanted to have this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**ExifTool**](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) should meet your requirements. It is *immensely* powerful, supports a huge number of [file types](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#supported) and [metatags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/index.html), and allows for complex Perl conditional expressions and config files based on tags and various other criteria. I would advise you to read the [documentation](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html) completely, especially the [section](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/filename.html) devoted to renaming files and creating destination directories based on user-specified criteria. Finally, if you ever get confused or stuck then posting on the [forum](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/) is sure to help you out since the developer and community are very helpful.

As a small and fairly simple example, the following command will move all recognised image files that have *either* a width of 1024px *or* height of 480px *and* (in both cases) a file size of less than 200KB into a directory (which will be created if required) called `Moved`:

```
exiftool -if "((($ImageWidth==1024) || ($ImageHeight==480)) && ($FileSize#<204800))" -directory=Moved *.*
```

Note: Here $ is followed by a tag name, and # is optionally appended to disable print conversion (i.e. to use numerical format for file size instead of human-readable format like KB, MB etc.). Again, it's all explained in the documentation.

Comment: Yep. This seems to be the thing. Let me just check it out before I give a final opinion.

Comment: Sorry about the delay but work has been overbearing. I've tried it and it is pretty much what I wanted. Thank you!